# Ignore related entity's property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using EF 4.3.1 code first to load data from entity Users

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<UserFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

along with the Files

```
public class UserFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

using code

```
var users = Context.Users.Include(u => u.Files).ToList();
```

Now this works, but the files are potentially quite large. What I'd like to do is load everything except the actual `Data` property, so that a long list of users with just their file names can be efficiently displayed. **Is there some clean way to approach this?**

My best idea so far is introducing another entity `File` related 1-1 to `UserFile` and containing only the `Data` field, with `Name` remaining in `UserFile`. I'd rather not add another redundant table (from DB PoV) just to make loading easier for EF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to create a `UserBasicFile` entity that includes everything but the data, and then make `UserFile` extend `UserBasicFile`, and include the `Data` property. That way if you have utility functions that only require the basic information they could require `UserBasicFile`s, and `UserFile`s could still be provided to those functions.

Remember that you don't necessarily have to have two tables in order to have two entity types.

Comment: Looks very promising. Will the derived entity be automatically mapped to the same table? Or do I need to add some mapping config and/or DbContext property?